# Do passive RC filters need ground?

Tags: audio, analog, filter, passive-filter

So, after a bit of searching I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere, at least not in an easy to understand manner.

Ok, lets set a scenario, if we have an audio input (in my project it would be buffered by a op amp in a 3403 quad op amp IC) and have that go into a passive RC filter (possibly 3 band) and have the output of that go into an overdrive circuit.

Question: Does that RC filter need a ground to filter to, or could I instead wire that to a second "identical" overdrive circuit and have part of my signal filter to od1 and the other part to od2?

Just a curious question, since all I can find are explanations of how RC filters filter to ground, but as I understand it, the filter works by having the "unwanted" frequencies follow a path of least resistance to ground, by that logic I would think that it doesn't matter whether that path is to ground or to some other part of the circuit.

Edit 1: Hypothetical schematic added.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3YTir.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The filter generally connects to the audio return path. In a single ended connection, yes that is ground. But in a balanced audio connection, it is the inverted leg.

Comment: and is the ground absolutely necesary in a unbalanced connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be *ground*.

In the Low Pass Filter, the capacitor needs to be connected to an AC ground. This basically means a constant (DC) offset from true (signal) ground. So, it could be connected to a 5 V battery (the other end of which *is* connected to ground).

This could have some subtle implications when the circuit starts up, but from a signal point of view, it's identical.

In general, the filter could be considered to have 2 inputs, and the output is a (linear) combination of the signals on each input. Note that the transfer function from each input may (will be in the R.C case) different. For the R.C LFP, the transfer function from the 'normal' input is a low pass; the transfer function from the 'other input' (the bottom of the capacitor) is a high-pass function. Obviously you don't want to *add* high frequency noise to your circuit, so you connect it to a low noise node --e.g. Ground; but if you did want to, you could connect it to wherever you want.

Comment: this proyect has been on the sideburner for a long time but thanks for your reply, the way you explain it as being a HPF from the capacitor side of the ciruit really helps clear it up, the purpose of this would be to esentially use the filter as a splitter that sends most of the lows down one path and most of the highs down anouther path, I'm now really excited to get started again, might have to dust off the idea notebook haha, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be able to return current to the source. This is to form a complete circuit for current from the source to flow around.

That return is most often ground.

It could conceivably also be the positive supply rail, provided the positive supply is well-bypassed to ground near the source circuit.

If your "overdrive" circuit has low output impedance and shares ground with the buffer circuit, that will most likely also work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with the possitive supply rail, because i have a bias voltage supply, the audio signal comming in, and the supply that powers the op-amps.

Comment: The overdrive circuit is designed around the same op-amp as the buffer in the schematic, followed by a active filter using also the same op amp, at the end there is an output buffer, my plan was to split the audio into treble and bass, and have them each go through their own overdrive/active filter section to late be joined again right before the output buffer

Answer (score 1):

Filters are two (or more) port circuits. It is typical for a filter to have a common terminal shared by the input and output ports. This common terminal is also often identified as the circuit *ground*. However, the common terminal could be at any potential. It does not necessarily need to be the chosen ground of a circuit. Nor is it necessarily the case that the input and output ports of a filter need to have a common terminal.

That being said, there are often advantages in designing filters to have a common input/output terminal which is ground.